# Timing requirements to avoid "Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream"

Tags: java, linux, windows, gzip, eof

I have a log analyzing tool that needs to grab *.gz files from Linux servers and unzip them on both Linux and Windows clients. I am getting "Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream" in many instances, which I assume is a difference in detail in the files on Linux and Windows.

Below is my function. It's pretty basic. How do I improved it to prevent the EOF error?

The "**in**" symbol is a FileInputStream that is created when constructing the class that this function is part of.

```
public void unzip(File fileTo) throws IOException {
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileTo);
    LOGGER.info("Setting up the file for outputstream : "+fileTo);
    try {
      in = new GZIPInputStream(in);
      byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
      int noRead;
      while ((noRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
          out.write(buffer, 0, noRead);
      }
    } finally {
        try { out.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

I changed from the above to this and now it works. It seems that it was trying to load the output stream before it was done loading the input stream.

```
        public void unzip(File fileTo, String f) throws IOException,           
            EOFException, InterruptedException {
        LOGGER.info("Setting up the file for outputstream : "+fileTo);
        GZIPInputStream cIn = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileTo);
        fileTo.setReadable(true, false);
        fileTo.setWritable(true, false);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
        int noRead;
        for (int i = 10; i > 0 && cIn.available() == 1; i--) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        try {
            while ((noRead = cIn.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, noRead);
            }
        } finally {
            try { out.close();cIn.close();in.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
```

Comment: If a file fails to open, can you read it using a default tool (such as Winzip or 7zip)? If so, the problem is in your Gzip library, if not, the files are corrupt and the code here is not the culpit either.

Comment: I think you are correct -- I think the problem is elsewhere. It looks like there is a ascii xfer taking place when it should be binary.

Comment: Turns out... no. This code plods along until it just bails out with the EOF error. Desktop tools open the archive correctly.

Comment: Solved it... rep is too low to answer it for myself though. lol